# Jquery push all li's ID's into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, dom, html-lists

I need to push all my ID's into an array, both ways I've tried this only pushes the first ID into the array:

```
  var some = [];
  $('ul#jdLists li').each(function () {
   some.push([$('ul#jdLists li').attr("id")]);
  });
```

This returns the correct number of items in the array but with the ID of the first li

or

```
    var some = [];                
    some.push([$('ul#jdLists li').attr("id")]);
```

this returns a single item with the first li ID

thanks

Comment: `.attr` and other getter methods get the value from the first selected element because there's no way of knowing which element you want to get the attribute from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This piece of code: `some.push([$('ul#jdLists li').attr("id")]);` will push id of first `li` found by `ul#jdLists li` selector, what you need to do is to get id of each `li`, which can be done inside `each` function:

```
var some = [];
$('ul#jdLists li').each(function () {
   some.push($(this).attr("id"));
   // or
   some.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Using `some.push(this.id)` would save creating a new jQuery object for every element.

Comment: Yeah, I've edited my answer to include it, thanks for comment.

Comment: that worked like a charm, thanks I was close but yet still far off

Answer (score 4):

or you can use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var ids = $('ul#jdLists li').map(function () {
   return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: A much more elegant solution IMO

Answer (score 0):

```
var some = [];
$('ul#jdLists li').each(function (i, el) {
   some.push(el.id);
});
```